# Convert sources to UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: powershell, utf-8, character-encoding

I try to convert all my source files from a target folder to the UTF-8 (without BOM) encoding.
I use the following PowerShell script:

```
$MyPath = "D:\my projects\etc\"
Get-ChildItem $MyPath\* -Include *.h, *.cpp, *.c | Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName  
    $Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($_.FullName, $content, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)    
}
cmd /c pause | out-null
```

it works fine if the files are already **not** in UTF-8. But if some file was already in UTF-8 no-BOM, all the national symbols become converted to unknown symbols (for example if I run the script again). How the script can be changed to fix the problem?

Comment: That sounds like the file is actually in some other encoding. Can you show an example of this corruption (actual hex bytes in the input and the output, probably just a few representative characters)?

Comment: Without a BOM `Get-Content` doesn't recognize the content of the file as UTF-8 anymore, so it reads the file as an ANSI file, thus mis-interpreting special characters. What problem are you trying to solve by removing the BOM in the first place?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I need to convert all the files exactly into UTF-8-no-BOM because using BOM is officially not recommended, I am sure that this is the most correct decision, and also because Microsoft Visual C++ compiler doesn't work with BOM and [Qt framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/index.html).

Comment: "Officially not recommended"? By whom? Also, [related](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/22/new-options-for-managing-character-sets-in-the-microsoft-cc-compiler/).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers by Unicode standard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom/2223926#2223926

Comment: Please actually read the section that is quoted from the standard and also the comments to that answer.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: A pragmatic summary would be: The Unicode standard _allows_ a UTF-8 "BOM" (Unicode signature), but neither recommends nor discourages its use.
In practice, many utilities on Unix-like platforms and, e.g., Java's standard libraries neither expect nor know how to handle such a BOM, so it is best avoided in cross-platform use.
Conversely, on Windows, legacy utilities and Windows PowerShell (as opposed to PowerShell _Core_) require this BOM to recognize and process UTF-8 files correctly.

Comment: @mklement0 My focus was mostly on the practical application in Windows environments, but yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) points out in a comment, the problem is that ***Windows PowerShell*, in the absence of a BOM, defaults to interpreting files as "ANSI"-encoded**, i.e., the encoding implied by the legacy system locale (ANSI code page), as reflected by the .NET Framework (but not .NET *Core*) in [`[System.Text.Encoding]::Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_Encoding_Default).

Given that, based on your follow-up comments, **the BOM-less files among your input files are a *mix* of Windows-1251-encoded and UTF-8 files**, you **must examine their *content*** to determine their specific encoding:

- Read each file with `-Encoding Utf8` and test if the resulting string contains the Unicode [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (`U+FFFD`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm). If it does, the implication is that the file is *not* UTF-8, because this special character is used to signal that byte sequences were encountered that aren't valid in UTF-8.
- If the file isn't valid UTF-8, simply read the file again *without* specifying `-Encoding`, which causes Windows PowerShell to interpret the file as Windows-1251-encoded, given that that is the encoding (code page) implied by your system locale.

```
$MyPath = "D:\my projects\etc"
Get-ChildItem $MyPath\* -Include *.h, *.cpp, *.c | Foreach-Object {
    # Note:
    #  * the use of -Encoding Utf8 to first try to read the file as UTF-8.
    #  * the use of -Raw to read the entire file as a *single string*.
    $content = Get-Content -Raw -Encoding Utf8 $_.FullName  

    # If the replacement char. is found in the content, the implication
    # is that the file is NOT UTF-8, so read it again *without -Encoding*,
    # which interprets the files as "ANSI" encoded (Windows-1251, in your case).
    if ($content.Contains([char] 0xfffd)) {
      $content = Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName  
    }

    # Note the use of WriteAllText() in lieu of WriteAllLines()
    # and that no explicit encoding object is passed, given that
    # .NET *defaults* to BOM-less UTF-8.
    # CAVEAT: There's a slight risk of data loss if writing back to the input
    #         file is interrupted.
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, $content)    
}
```

A **faster alternative** is to use `[IO.File]::ReadAllText()` with a UTF-8 encoding object that *throws an exception* when invalid-as-UTF-8 bytes are encountered (PSv5+ syntax):

```
$utf8EncodingThatThrows = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false, $true)

# ...

  try {
     $content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName, $utf8EncodingThatThrows)
  } catch [Text.DecoderFallbackException] {         
     $content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName, [Text.Encoding]::Default)
  }

# ...
```

---

**Adapting the above solutions to PowerShell *Core* / .NET Core:**

- PowerShell *Core* defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8, so simply omitting `-Encoding` doesn't work for reading ANSI-encoded files.
- Similarly, `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default` *invariably* reports UTF-8 in .NET Core.

Therefore, you must **manually determine the active system locale's ANSI code page and obtain the corresponding encoding object**:

```
$ansiEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(
  [int] (Get-ItemPropertyValue HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage ACP)
)
```

You then need to pass this encoding explicitly to `Get-Content -Encoding` ( `Get-Content -Raw -Encoding $ansiEncoding $_.FullName`) or to the .NET methods (`[IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName, $ansiEncoding)`).

---

#### Original form of the answer: for input files that are all UTF-8-encoded already:

Therefore, **if some of your UTF-8-encoded files (already) *are* BOM-less, you must *explicitly* instruct `Get-Content` to treat them as UTF-8, using `-Encoding Utf8`** - otherwise they will be misinterpreted, if they contain characters outside the 7-bit ASCII range:

```
$MyPath = "D:\my projects\etc"
Get-ChildItem $MyPath\* -Include *.h, *.cpp, *.c | Foreach-Object {
    # Note:
    #  * the use of -Encoding Utf8 to ensure the correct interpretation of the input file
    #  * the use of -Raw to read the entire file as a *single string*.
    $content = Get-Content -Raw -Encoding Utf8 $_.FullName  

    # Note the use of WriteAllText() in lieu of WriteAllLines()
    # and that no explicit encoding object is passed, given that
    # .NET *defaults* to BOM-less UTF-8.
    # CAVEAT: There's a slight risk of data loss if writing back to the input
    #         file is interrupted.
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, $content)    
}
```

Note: BOM-less UTF-8 files do not need rewriting in your scenario, but doing so is benign and simplifies the code; the **alternative** would be to **test if the first 3 bytes of each file are the UTF-8 BOM** and skip such a file:
`$hasUtf8Bom = "$(Get-Content -Encoding Byte -First 3 $_.FullName)" -eq '239 187 191'` (Windows PowerShell) or
`$hasUtf8Bom = "$(Get-Content -AsByteStream -First 3 $_.FullName)" -eq '239 187 191'` (PowerShell Core).

As an aside: Should there be input files with a non-UTF8 encoding (e.g., UTF-16), the solution still works *as long as these files have a BOM*, because **PowerShell (quietly) gives precedence to a BOM over the encoding specified via `-Encoding`**.

Note that using `-Raw` / `WriteAllText()` to read / write the files *as a whole* (single string) not only speeds up processing a little, but ensures that the following characteristics of each input file are *preserved*:

- the specific newline style (CRLF (Windows) vs. LF-only (Unix))
- whether the last line has a trailing newline.

By contrast, not using `-Raw` (line-by-line reading) and using `.WriteAllLines()` does *not* preserve these characteristics: you invariably get the platform-appropriate newlines (in Windows PowerShell, always CRLF) and you always get at trailing newline.

---

Note that the multi-platform **Powershell *Core*** edition **sensibly *defaults to UTF-8*** when reading a file without a BOM and **also by default *creates* BOM-less UTF-8 files** - creating a UTF-8 file *with* BOM requires explicit opt-in with `-Encoding utf8BOM`.

Therefore, **a PowerShell *Core* solution is much simpler**:

```bsh
# PowerShell Core only.

$MyPath = "D:\my projects\etc"
Get-ChildItem $MyPath\* -Include *.h, *.cpp, *.c | Foreach-Object {
    # * Read the file at hand (UTF8 files both with and without BOM are 
    #   read correctly).
    # * Simply rewrite it with the *default* encoding, which in 
    #   PowerShell Core is BOM-less UTF-8.
    # Note the (...) around the Get-Content call, which is necessary in order
    # to write back to the *same* file in the same pipeline.
    # CAVEAT: There's a slight risk of data loss if writing back to the input
    #         file is interrupted.
    (Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName) | Set-Content -NoNewline $_.FullName
}
```

---

#### Faster .NET-type-based solution

The above solutions work, but **`Get-Content` and `Set-Content` are relatively slow**, so using .NET types to both read and rewrite the files will perform better.

As above, **no encoding must explicitly be specified** in the following solution (not even in *Windows PowerShell*), because **.NET itself has commendably defaulted to BOM-less UTF-8 since its inception** (while still recognizing a UTF-8 BOM *if* present):

```
$MyPath = "D:\my projects\etc"
Get-ChildItem $MyPath\* -Include *.h, *.cpp, *.c | Foreach-Object {
  # CAVEAT: There's a slight risk of data loss if writing back to the input
  #         file is interrupted.
  [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText(
    $_.FullName,
    [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName)
  )   
}
```

Comment: @VladimirBershov: P.S.: I've switched from `-like` to `.Contains()` to test for the replacement character, which is both simpler and presumably faster.

Answer (score 0):

Right check a `BOM` presence e.g. using the following template (apply an action instead of the comments about `BOM`):

```
$ps1scripts = Get-ChildItem .\*.ps1 -Recurse      # change to match your circumstances
foreach ( $ps1script in $ps1scripts ) {
    $first3 = $ps1script | Get-Content -Encoding byte -TotalCount 3
    $first3Hex = '{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}' -f $first3[0],$first3[1],$first3[2]
    $first2Hex = '{0:x2}{1:x2}'       -f $first3[0],$first3[1]

    if ( $first3Hex -eq 'EFBBBF' )     {
        # UTF-8 BOM

    } elseif ( $first2Hex -eq 'fffe' ) {
        # UCS-2LE BOM

    } elseif ( $first2Hex -eq 'feff' ) {
        # UCS-2BE BOM

    } else {
        # unknown (no BOM)

    }
}
```

Note that the above template was derived from my older script; you can change the first line as follows:

```
$MyPath = "D:\my projects\etc\"
$ps1scripts = Get-ChildItem $MyPath\* -Include *.h, *.cpp, *.c
```